# How do I format axes on line chart google chart material?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm having problems formatting the axes of material charts.

Using "classic" line chart if I would like to format my vertical axis with a dollar sign, I would do
`{vAxes: { 0: {title: 'Amount',format: '$#,##'}}}`
Making it look like so: [image]

I would've thought I could change to `{axes: {y: {Amount: {format:'$#,##', label:'Amount'} } } }` after reading what little docs exist for the material charts, but this didn't work at all.

Also, I have date on the horizontal axis, and the default formatting is sh*t! I can't figure out how to override that formatting either. Note this is on the axis it self I'm trying to format.

With the horizontal I tried setting `hAxis: {format:'YYYY-MM-DD'}` but that didn't work.

My main question would be: Does anyone know of a complete documentation of the material charts? The one I've been using is [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Material).

Second question: How do I format the values on the axes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the options simply are not available on *Material* charts...

see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

---

when using a *Core* chart instead, there is an option that will get the chart "close" to *Material* chart...

```
theme: 'material'
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date','Date');
  data.addColumn('number','Value');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2017, 1, 12), 250],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 13), 200],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 14), 150]
  ]);

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
    },
    theme: 'material',
    vAxis: {
      format: '$#,##',
      title: 'Amount'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: thanks! But looking at that list I see a bunch of v- and h-axis properties that are not working. However format is not among them, which suggests to me that it should work... ? You are not aware of some more extensive docs on the material charts? I will use the theme from now on! Thanks for that tip!

Comment: no more docs that i know of, only other info can be found in the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes), not much there for _material_...

Comment: no.. sad that it should be so difficult to find documentation on that part of google charts. Anyways, thanks for your answer!